# Agreements, Tax, Banking in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In my iTunes Connect, the following message showing:

> The following contracts are expired: iOS iAd Agreement. This could be affecting the availability of your apps. To request and complete your updated contracts, go to the Agreements, Tax, and Banking module.

How do I fix the message?

Comment: Try sending them an email.

Comment: Sure. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: I have always been able to do this from within iTunes connect.

Comment: I see an iCon called "Agreements, Tax and Banking" did you click that?

Comment: Yes, I clicked that and checked expiration.

Comment: The problem has been resolved. Somehow it seems time lag.